# Ejecutar con docker-compose archivo yml en concreto

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Como podria hacer el build y ejecutar un archivo yml en concreto de docker-compose

```
# ls

certbot.sh  docker-compose-dev.yml  Dockerfile       manage.py  nginx_dev  requirements.txt  templates
data        docker-compose.yml      image_compresor  nginx      README.md  static            web
```

Tengo el docker-compose.yml que se ejecuta de forma predeterminada cuando ejecuto

```
docker-compose build --no-cache && docker-compose up -d
```

Mi pregunta seria como hago que me pille el docker-compose-dev.yml ? cuando ejecuto estos
dos comandos.

O se tiene que configurar algo dentro del DockerFile ?

Comment: Añade `-f docker-compose-dev.yml` a los comandos que tienes. `docker-compose build --no-cache -f docker-compose-dev.yml  && docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up - d`

Comment: si me va el -f si lo pongo asi docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml build --no-cache , Perfecto gracias @Jacobo

Comment: @Jacobo dale la respuesta profa, asi la cierro.